# How to use goja when js file include other js file?

Tags: javascript, go

I use goja to call js function in my golang project, but when goja RunCode js file include other js file will cause err. for example below.

```
    mathBytes, err := os.ReadFile("./calculate.js")
    vm, err := js.RunCode(string(mathBytes))
    if err != nil {
        logger.Logger.Errorf("goja vm run code err:%+v", err)
        return nil, err
    }
```

the calculate.js file as below

```
import * as functions from './formula.js';
import { get, cloneDeep } from './lodash.js';

const fnNames = Object.keys(functions).filter((key) => key !== 'default');
const fns = fnNames.map((key) => functions[key]);
```

Comment: As of now, it's not supported yet. See https://github.com/dop251/goja/issues/348.